# Trello OAuth 1.0 authentication

Tags: api, oauth, trello

I was trying to integrate the Trello authentication flow for a server side application (using Java).

Now If I do the OAuth dance manually I'm able to get the OAuth access token and I can make API calls (so far so good).

BUT when using in production the callback POST to my server does not carry the oauth_token and oauth_verifier or code query string parameters ... instead it delivers the token as a URL fragment

http://example.com/rest/callback#token=32849234

This is useless for a server side application as fragments are omitted by the browser and are never recieved on the backend side.

So I'm not able to perform the last step - getting the access token!

Now is there a way to get the OAuth callback to call my server the correct way (as specified), the two provided options postMessage and fragment will not work for a server side implementation.

I have read:

- https://developers.trello.com/authorize
- https://trello.com/c/fD8ErOzA/26-getting-a-user-token-and-oauth-urls

and it seems other developers have similar issues.

Now I can make the user copy past the verification code manually ... but this is not user friendly.

Comment: Have you tried the [client lib](https://developers.trello.com/clientjs)?

Comment: The client lib is javascript ... my intention was to do all on the backend side. I already have several OAuth integrations present on the backend ... doing only one in javascript just because the OAuth callback is not properly implemented seems out of scope and brings additional trouble.

Comment: I guess that's by design then. Token only being readable from a browser i.e where the user is.